# how to Add xml Resource bundle to spring config

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to add **xml** Resource Bundle to spring xml file and to get it's value later in the code.
I got error: " No message found under code 'node_list.severity.low' for locale 'ja_JP'."

Resource Bundle xml (List_ja_JP.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>This is severity list</comment>
<entry key="node_list.severity">severity</entry>
<entry key="node_list.severity.low">Low</entry>
<entry key="node_list.severity.medium">Medium</entry>
<entry key="node_list.severity.high">High</entry>
<entry key="node_list.severity.urgent">Urgent</entry>
</properties>
```

The config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="handleListResourceBundleBean"
      class="org.emiller.springcore.HandleListResourceBundle">
    <constructor-arg ref="readListBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="listResourceBean"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="org.emiller.springcore.List"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="readListBean" class="org.emiller.springcore.ReadList"/> 
</beans>
```

The code trying to get list item:

```
public class ReadList implements IReadList {
@Override
public String getList() {
 ApplicationContext context = 
 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/emiller/springcore/config.xml");
 ResourceBundleMessageSource listObj=   
 (ResourceBundleMessageSource)context.getBean("listResourceBean");
 return listObj.getMessage("node_list.severity.low",null, Locale.JAPAN);
}
}
```

Thanks a lot

Eli Miller

Comment: There is no reference to your resource bundle in either the code or the configuration that you have included.  Might this be the root of your problem?

Comment: Can you send me example of config file  + code using xml resource bundle with referenace you just mention? Thanks